# No Audio on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, audio

I tried many answers on different websites. Raspberrypi.org, this site, linux.com, and others I cannot list. I tried Analogue with `sudo raspi-config`. I also tried `amixer cset numid=3 1`. I tried updating and upgrading. But nothing is working. I tried the hello.bin wave sound, that worked. But nothing else is working. I verified the speakers work on a Windows PC and macOS X Mojave. But they don't work on Raspbian. Do I need to re-install the OS? If so how can I back up the configs without losing everything again?

Your help is appreciated. I'm not very experienced with my Pi, so please be patient with me, as I am autistic.

EDIT: The hello thing does work. But no other videos or .wav files are working. I would set the volume to max, and then right-click the icon and click 'Analogue'. But then the sound resets to mute every time.

EDIT 2: VLC Media Player

EDIT 3: I just edited the file and saved it. I rebooted and tried the audio, but it still resets to mute every time I turn the volume>0

Comment: `nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` and change `defaults.ctl.card 0` and `defaults.pcm.card 0` to `defaults.ctl.card 1`, `defaults.pcm.card 1` then save alsa.conf file. Finally `reboot`. Note that you need a `reboot` after any configuration.

Comment: I just edited the file and saved it. I rebooted and tried the audio, but it still resets to mute every time I turn the volume>0

Comment: So, the problem is not that the audio is disabled, it's about resetting config? Right?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not an expert on things. I'm not sure which configs to change. I already did your response, but didn't work. I _really_ don't want to re-install Raspbian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer myself. I feel very dumb of not trying this out, but here is the A:

Without selecting an output device, I just turned the volume to 100% and hit play on VLC. Ta-da.........

I can't believe I didn't think of trying this out.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.